# Retrieving the script(.js) in master page from all pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page and in that i have written the code for .js file as :

```
<script src="../../../scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the pages are created in different folder structure.

So if the `page` is not created in the folder and if it is out side the folder then the `javascript` is not working.

**for example:**

*`master page file:` masterpages/layoutmaster.master*

**pages:**

*pages/folder1/default1.aspx*

*pages/folder2/default2.aspx*

*default3.aspx*

As per the above example the **default3.aspx** page of the `javascript` file is not accessing.

Comment: The layoutmaster.master file contains the scripts in the above mentioned path and the pages that are in folder level or not in the folders level the path should work. i tried with the absolute path also but no luck? can any one help on this issue?

Comment: If you're creating ASP.Net page, you can simply type `src="` in the 2010 version and it will pop-up a little thing to click on where you can then locate your js and select it. Once done, it'll create the hyperlink automajikally!

Answer (score 1):

By using a relative path "../js/script.js" it is going to go up a folder, so in order to prevent that, just use an absolute path, such as "/js/script.js"

Comment: The layoutmaster.master file contains the scripts in the above mentioned path and the pages that are in folder level or not in the folders level the path should work. i tried with the absolute path also but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a relative path to the script like the one you're using:

```
<script src="../../../scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Use an absolute path:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: if i am using this under the view page source the error message is as follows "  <span><h1>Server Error in '/NewFolder' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></h1>

            <h2> <i>HTTP Error 404 - Not Found.</i> </h2></span>"

Comment: Are you able to access the file from "http://yourapplication.com/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"? If not and you're sure the file is there, maybe you need to ignore the route. [More info on routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#scenarios_when_routing_is_not_applied)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to point out your javascript file in `src`  with `../../../` and this means jump out from the current directory to the third level, as `../` means go up to folder only once from the current directory.

so use it as

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

By the way, if you needed to go back two directories, you would use `../../` and so on, and so on.